# .htaccess redirect to both index.html and .php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a landing page html witch the domain points to but if I access /index.php it redirects back to index.html.

How could I make the index.php accessible?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.nz$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.co.nz/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Show us `mod_rewrite` log. I hope `/index.php` does not contain any redirects inside? Also do you really need 301 redirect (= 2 browser requests) instead of one internal redirect (but URL in browser will not change)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redireting everything to the html file.

Try:

```
# Enable rewiting
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

# set 'default' file
DirectoryIndex index.html

# everything else goes to the index.php file, except your sites assets/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|index\.html|images|css|javascript)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```